# How to run code outside of meteor method simulation

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, ddp

I've got a very interesting issue in my Meteor js app: when I call a meteor method inside of my template's onCreated method the callback for that method call sometimes returns immediately with undefined as the result. It turns out that this is because the template got created as a result of running a meteor method simulation.

Two questions:

1. Is is this a bug? It certainly isn't the behavior that I expected.
2. How can I work around this without using weird hacks like setTimeout (and, by the way `Meteor.setTimeout` isn't allowed inside of method simulations)?

Some Code:

```
// My Template (Not my real code, just to demonstrate)
Template.saying.onCreated(() => {
  var tmpl = Template.instance();
  tmpl.saying = new ReactiveVar();

  Meteor.call('getSaying', (err, saying) => {
    // If called inside of a simulation, saying is null
    tmpl.saying.set(saying);
  });
});


// Assume that the above template is used in an {{each}} block
// and somewhere in my code I call this
Items.insert({});

// Because Items.insert wraps a meteor method which also runs as a
// simulation on the client, then the Template.saying.onCreated
// callback will be called in the context of an active simulation,
// which means that 'getSaying' method call will return immediately
// with undefined as the result.
```

Comment: This feels like a pretty inefficient pattern - you're going to be calling the server once/template in a loop whenever the parent template is rendered just to set some reactive variable. Even if you make this work it's going to be slow. Why not put the data that you're getting from the server into a collection and let Meteor push it to the client?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the pattern I have to use, each template needs it's own token, and those tokens have to be generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities to avoid simulation:

1. Define the method in a server side only file
2. Use isClient. When the simulation is run it will evaluate to true

   ```
   if (Meteor.isClient) {
   // on the client, the return value of a stub is ignored
   return;
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work, for two reasons:
1. The behavior I'm getting is with the method defined only on the server side (however the outer method is defined both client and server side, and should be that way).
2. The problem is that under the circumstances (inside of a simulation), the return value is not ignored, but I want it to be.

Comment: Well I don't see how the value is not ignored with code above. How are you sure about that? If it's a simulation then the condition will for sure evaluate to true

Comment: The problem is that an undefined return value as in your example above will be passed to the meteor method callback if the meteor method was called inside of a meteor method simulation.